# For a inbalance regarding has_many through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am wondering when using has_many, :through, have I need to use it in balance in two models, for example Snippet1

```
A
has_many :c
bas_many :b through :c

B
has_many :c
bas_many :a through :c
```

If I use the  following snippet2,

```
  A
    has_many :c
    bas_many :b through :c

    B
    has_many :c
```

I am wondering difference bwteen Snippet1 and Snippet2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that in the second snippet you cannot use association helper [methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) from `B` instance side.

```
# Would work only in the first snippet
b = B.take
b.as

# Would work in both snippets
a = A.take
a.bs
```

---

And no, you don't have to use this on both sides. Only if you need.